# get_post_meta with related user

Tags: user-roles, post-meta

When I call post with `get_post_meta` I get all posts.I would like to get related post from user when using `get_post_meta`. How would I achieve this?

Example: If I am logged in as foo than I would like to get all posts by foo.

Comment: Sorry about my english. I got all post. That's what I don't want.

Example I was login with Author and I would like to get author's post only. Which function do i have to use?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `get_posts()`

```
$current_user = get_current_user_id();

$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'author'      => $current_user,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$all_posts = get_posts( $args );
```